# java- oauth with google picasa data api

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, picasa

I have a requirement where I want images to be stored/retrieved from a single Google Account (this account has picasa storage). This should be done even if the user who is logged in to my web app, is different from the single google account (which has picasa storage).

(I plan to store all images used by this web app in Picasa Storage).

I couldnt find any example/reference for this particular scenario-- the docs talk about regular oauth authentication, where the user who is using the web app, gives permission to the web app to access his picasa images... What I want is, the single stored user (who has the images stored in his picasa account) is authenticated by the web app, even if a different user is logged in to the web app... Now the application can display images from the authenticated user's picasa albums...Can this be implemented? And ideally by using the google data apis client library for Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is provided in Google Documentation of the API- at http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#ClientLogin

The user id and password has to be stored in the application, and irrespective of whichever user is using the application, auth into Picasa will be done for the stored user only.

This is referred to as Single-user "installed" client authentication in the docs...